# Получить ссылку на объект сцены

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

И снова ночи доброй.

Возникла проблема с получением ссылки на элемент сцены, подгруженной из FXML файла.
Что-то нигде не нахожу мануала, как с ним работать. Нет ничего, напоминающего getElementById, или вроде того.

Ссылка на объект нужна для того, чтобы по полученной ссылке на сцену я бы далее сослался на, к примеру, грид с целью повесить обработчик на группу элементов, находящуюся внутри грида (кнопки, лэйблы, текст и т.д.).

Как подгружаю сцену:

```
Parent root = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("/sample/mysample.fxml"));
mystage.setScene(new Scene(root));
```

Единственное, что вижу, это метод `getChildrenUnmodifiable()`, но в спецификации сказано,
что это `read-only list`.

Означает ли это, что такой возможности вообще нет, в смысле вешать обработчики и изменять содержимое объектов внутри грида (список кнопок у меня там)?

Comment: @Vladislav  Romarov, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Да я над ответом думал ))))). Нашел в справочнике описание как раз подходящее)). Что ж, буду пробовать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм. А почему бы не использовать в FXML файле на нужных элементах интерфейса такой параметр, как fx:id?

Суть в том, что затем в классе-контроллере будет создано поле класса, которое будет ссылаться на нужный вам объект, и через это поле можно будет делать с объектом что хочешь. Например, создать GridPane по такому способу, а затем в методе initialize() контроллера накидывать кнопки и вешать к ним обработчики.

**Обновление**

[[@Vladislav  Romarov](/users/24213/vladislav-romarov)](/users/24213/vladislav-romarov) В классе-контроллере должна быть объявлена переменная grid1 с префиксом @FXML. Eclipse автоматически их добавляет. После можно делать с ней что угодно: работать в методах класса-контроллера или же передать через getGrid() в другой класс и там что-то с ним делать.